# Wrong number of arguments with NUnit TestCaseData

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm trying to set up some test cases for my test:

```
public IEnumerable<TestCaseData> size_tests()
{
    yield return new TestCaseData(new string[] { "XS", "XL", "M" })
        .Returns(new SortedVariantAttributeModel {
            Values = new string[] { "XS", "M", "XL" },
            PrimaryValue = "XS"
        });
}

[Test, TestCaseSource("size_tests")]
public SortedVariantAttributeModel Should_map_SortedVariantAttributes(string[] sizes)
{
    // ...
}
```

When I try to run this test, I get:

> Test Failed - Should_map_SortedVariantAttributes("XS","XL","M")
>
> Message: Wrong number of arguments provided

Judging by the error it seems to unwrap the array and try to apply it to the test function, but that results in problems of course. How do I solve this?

Comment: What version of NUnit are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get this working, you need to wrap the arguments in an array like this, `new[] { new string[] { "XS", "XL", "M" } }`. This causes NUnit to treat the string array as the first argument to a method instead of a series of string arguments.

I believe that you are using NUnit 2.x because your data source is not static. I simplified your code and tested the workaround in NUnit 2.6.4 and 3.4.1.

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> Data()
{
    yield return new TestCaseData(new[] { new string[] { "XS", "XL", "M" } });
    yield return new TestCaseData(new[] { new string[] { "S", "M", "XXL", "L" } });
}

[TestCaseSource(nameof(Data))]
public void TestStringArrayArguments(string[] sizes)
{
    Assert.That(sizes.Length, Is.GreaterThan(1));
}
```

Comment: Nice; this is one of the places where the new `nameof(...)` feature of C# is useful. There is another way to force a correct overload, and that is `yield return new TestCaseData((object)(new string[] { "XS", "XL", "M" }));`. The constructor has several overloads, and the one overload with `params` can apply in two ways.

Comment: I ended up providing the details in a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant instance constructor has the following overloads:

```
public TestCaseData(params object[] args) { /* ... */ } //A

public TestCaseData(object arg) { /* ... */ } //B

public TestCaseData(object arg1, object arg2) { /* ... */ } //C

public TestCaseData(object arg1, object arg2, object arg3) { /* ... */ } //D
```

The overload with `params` can apply in two ways, either in the **normal form** where you give the object array explicitly in your code, or in the **expanded form** where you just specify a bunch of objects (zero or more) with commas and the compiler produces the array for you implicitly. See *§7.5.3.1 Applicable function member* in the C# spec.

When you do:

```
new TestCaseData(new string[] { "XS", "XL", "M" })
```

it becomes important that C# (as well as the CLR) has a dubious *array covariance* for arrays of reference types (`string` is a reference type). So your `string[]` "is" also an `object[]` (use covariance on the fact that a `string` is an `object`).

So overload `//A` applies in normal form. When normal form applies, `//A` in expanded form shall not be considered.

Overload `//B` in your use is also applicable, since a `string[]` is a `System.Array` which is an `object`.

However `//A` is considered more specific (all `object[]` are `object` but now vice versa) and is preferred over `//B`. So `//A` is used *in its normal form* which is not what you want. Your `Should_map_SortedVariantAttributes` takes one argument (called `sizes`), not three. Hence the problem.

A good solution is now easy:

```
new TestCaseData((object)(new string[] { "XS", "XL", "M" })) /* fixes your issue! */
```

Now we have an expression of type `object`. The overload `//A` is not applicable in its normal form anymore. So this time it is checked if `//A` is applicable in its expanded form, which it is.

Also `//B` is applicable here.

Either `//A` *in its expanded form* or `//B` would make your code work, so no matter what the C# overload resolution chooses in this case, we are happy.

In reality, the C# rules (§7.5.3.2) prefer a usual form over an *expanded form* in such cases, so `//B` is used. This is a nice thing, the compiler will not have to create an implicit length-1 object array.